# How to create a drop-down list of Groups for a form?

Tags: profile, groups, drop-down

Our organisation (a u3a) has many Groups. Each Group (apart from administrative Groups) has a Group coordinator. I have created a custom field ‘Coordinator of’ and would like the profile entry to be a multi select drop-down list containing the current list of Groups. (Some members coordinate more than one Group).

This is because although I can create a Group of Group Coordinators for mailing purposes, I like to add a token, indicating which Groups they coordinate, to the email.

There is a field in the profile for a contact for Group membership that does this. Can I use this somehow in a custom field or do I need to add a hook and write code?

We are working in Wordpress and I am very much a newbie.

Answer (score 0):

welcome - as i understand this, you want a 'multiple record' field on the contact, so you can then include a token which would list all the Groups they are a coordinator for? I am not sure if tokens currently work well for multiple records. I just set up a custom field on dmaster demo site, and that worked fine in terms of having my contact set up as coordinator for several groups. but i don't see the token for that field (which may be where you already got to?).

I did also try the Fuzion Token extension but no change there.

This old reply suggests it can be done [Tokens for Custom Field Set with Multiple Records](https://civicrm.stackexchange.com/questions/2558/tokens-for-custom-field-set-with-multiple-records) and there seems to be some suggestions here with more details, though for a different context

Comment: Thanks for this @petednz - fusion. I am happy for the custom field to return a string as it is very unlikely to contain more than 3 Groups. We can clearly do this using manual entry but that can result in typos. Your answer and included link makes me think that manual entry may be best, however.

Comment: "Some members coordinate more than one Group". wold it be worth thinking about doing a custom entity reference field as a single (not multiple) field (Group Coordinator 1), to work for the majority and then have Group Coordinator 2, 3 etc for those with multiples?